# Detect Skype call end on android

Tags: android, titanium, skype, appcelerator-mobile

I'm developing an Android app using Appcelerator Titanium. My app can initiate Skype call using Skype URI 
`Ti.Platform.openURL("skype:" + skypeId +"?call")` 
I want to detect Skype call end so that i can regain focus on my app. Any idea how can i make it? (native android solutions are welcomed too)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is not possible as the Skype application only provides an API for starting a call (as you already use it). Maybe you can try to use the `startActivityForResult()` [structure](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html). Although I think that this won't be successful either because the Skype app must be designed to support this style of activity calling and I doubt that.

Comment: i'm aware that Skype doesn't provide this feature in it's public API .. i'am looking for an alternative solution like using the NotificationManager, BroadcastReceiver, audio status change event or Voip system events for example ..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write an Android module and use the Audio Manager, audio focus. This can be a workaround for the implementation. I do not think Appcelerator provides anything out of the box for Audio Manager. We need to write a module for it, if this works out for you.